# Figurative meaning of ‘pagar la fianza’

Tags: traducción, expresiones, modismos

¡Hola! I understand that ‘pagar la fianza’ means ‘to pay bail’ but does it have an other figurative meaning. This is in reference to its use in Prince Royce and Shakira’s song [Déjà Vu](https://youtu.be/XEvKn-QgAY0) (which I love btw). ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no other meaning for `pagar la fianza` than "to pay the bail"

You can see that that such is the figurative role that it is also playing in the lyrics here.
The girl does not want to be hurt again and tries to avoid recurring into a distressing relationship wondering how to liberate the pain imprisoned inside her heart.

> ¿Quién puede hablar del amor?
> ¿Y defenderlo?
> Que levante la mano, por favor 
> **¿Quién puede hablar del dolor?** 
> ***Pagar la fianza*** 
> **Pa' que salga de mi corazón** 
> Si alguien va a hablar del amor 
> Te lo aseguro 
> Esa no voy a ser yo

> who can talk about the agony 
> ***pay the bail***
> so it's out of my heart

Comment: Or if translating it for a UK audience "stand bail". I did understand pay bail, obviously.

Comment: @ipp Thank you, you are right. I did not take into account the ‘pa’ que salga de mi corazón’. With it, the ‘pay the bail’ literal meaning fits right.

Comment: @rakesh-mhasawade you are welcome! (you may want to accept the answer if it worked for you)